# Nexttoken method is skipping if statement when traversing an array

Tags: java, tokenize

Building a nexttoken method for a turtle token program. One of the triggers for ending a token is if the string hits another letter while already having a letter in the substring, but the if statement is never entered. It does enter the statement if I specifically define the array index where I know a letter is.

Global variables:

```
  int Brackets = 0;
  String verdi;
  String[] strengarray = new String [30];
  TurtleTokenizer TT;
  int startIndex = 0;
  int endIndex;

public String nextToken() {

            strengarray = verdi.split("");
            boolean ok = true;
            boolean Letter = false;
            int  endtemp = endIndex;

              for(int i = startIndex; i<strengarray.length; i++)
               { 

                  if (strengarray[i].equals("F") || strengarray[i].equals("R") || strengarray[i].equals("L") ) // This if statement is never entered!
                   {
                      if( Letter == true)
                          break;
                      else
                       Letter = true;
                   }

                    if(strengarray[i].equals( "{"))
                    {
                        Brackets++;
                    }
                    if(strengarray[i].equals( "}"))
                    {
                        Brackets--;

                    }

                  endtemp = i;
                }
                            endIndex = endtemp;

              String sub = verdi.substring( startIndex,  endIndex);
             startIndex = endIndex;

                return sub + "\n"; 
    }
```

The hasmore method:

```
public boolean hasMoreTokens() {

        if (Brackets >0)
            return true;
        else
            return false; 
    }
```

The main method:

```
public class TestTurtle {
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {   

        String st = "F0R4L10";

    TurtleTokenizer Leonardo = new TurtleTokenizer(st);



  do 
    {
         System.out.println(Leonardo.nextToken() + "\n");
}
     while(Leonardo.hasMoreTokens());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you print out the value of `strengarray[i]` right before that `if` statement, is it what you expect it to be? I'm assuming you actually assign a value to `verdi` somewhere too.

Comment: Verdi = st in the constructor. 
You are right there is something wrong there, strengarray prints out: 041, this seems to be only the numbers. why will it not print the letters?

Comment: If you print out the value of `Verdi` right before you split it do you get what you expect?

Comment: Yes it contains the full string with letters, i wrote this the same way another time and it worked... Thanks for the help Mike!

Answer (score 0):

There has to have been a incoding error or something, wrote the same code another time and it worked.